# How to control position overlap on other elements?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to control a `position:relative` element to push down the element below it. At the moment, it's overlay on top of the element below.

Please have a look at my [**JSfiddle implementation**](https://jsfiddle.net/fkaufusi/ayjxb6ec/18/)

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://www.planetware.com/photos-large/USHI/hawaii-honolulu-beaches-oahu-kailua-beach.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="container">
      Overlap box - How can this box push down the text below, without overlap on top?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here
    </p>
    <p>
      Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your html for that. Just place the `.container`-div after the `.header`-div and set the `.container`-divs `margin-top` to a negative value.:

HTML

```
<div id="body">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="container">
Overlap box - How can this box push down the text below, without overlap on top?
</div>
<div>
<p>
Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here
</p>
<p>
Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here. Rest of the body content here.
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
  position:relative;
  background-image:url("https://www.planetware.com/photos-large/USHI/hawaii-honolulu-beaches-oahu-kailua-beach.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height:200px;
}

#container {
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  background-color:#ccc;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bqzh3nr8/

Answer (score 0):

Use Z-index: 1 for the element need to be displayed top and use z-index:0 which need to displayed inner.